# Why Herpes Vaccine Hasn't Been Discovered Yet While Corona Vaccines Find Its Way Within A Year?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, herpes

There is one question constantly running in my mind: how were COVID-19 vaccines discovered in a very short time span, but Herpes did not find its way even after years of painstaking research?

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herpes_simplex_research#Vaccine_research ?

Answer (score 5):

Two things that come to mind:

- Unlike COVID-19, the herpes virus does not completely shut down society. So there's much more incentive and hence funding to finding a vaccine for COVID-19.
- We already have researched (but not completed) vaccines for other corona-type diseases like SARS and MERS, and luckily this knowledge helped in accelerating the process of finding a vaccine for COVID-19. See e.g. [the recently published article 'Coronavirus vaccine development: from SARS and MERS to COVID-19'](https://jbiomedsci.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12929-020-00695-2).

Comment: I edited your answer to clarify.  The way you wrote it made it sound you were saying there was more incentive/funding for a herpes virus.